# Hadoop DFS start

Tags: hadoop

Hi all I am new in Hadoop Development. I just started with hadoop and installed Hadoop in my pc and started configuring it but, I am stuck in a place where I am trying to start DFS and I found following on my console

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
localhost: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

I have run the command $start-dfs.sh
I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Can anyone help me out of this issue I have set all the environment variable including `JAVA_HOME`.

.bash file

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop 
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native 
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin 
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java-7-openjdk-amd64 
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin 
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

Core-site.xml

```
<configuration> 
 <property> 
 <name>fs.default.name</name> 
 <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value> 
 </property> 
</configuration>
```

Please help me on this 
Thanks

Comment: Put here these a bit edited configure files, please.

Comment: .bash file 
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native 
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin 
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

Comment: Core-site.xml

<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
 </property>
</configuration>

Comment: Log files might give you more information about the error.

Comment: Check whether SSH server is running!